# How to pass and override configuration properties from command line in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

We have different kerberos login authentication keytabs for our hadoop cluster. Can I pass the keytab path flink command line client rather than specify it in flink-conf.yml? Or any another approaches to specific different configuration file from different applications. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can override configuration which is there in `flink-conf.yaml` using dynamic properties.
While running flink command (on yarn) you can use this:

```
bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yD property_name=value User_Jar
```

Answer (score -1):

You can override configuration in command line by setting arguments the following way:

```sh
./bin/flink run ./examples/batch/WordCount.jar \
                     --input file:///home/user/hamlet.txt --output file:///home/u
```

Then you can get this arguments in your code by using `ParameterTool`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ParameterTool command = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
    String inputFile = command.getRequired("input");
    String outputFile = command.getRequired("output");
}
```

References:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/cli.html